# Network Error Alert in Xcode Needed Urgently

Tags: ios, xcode, alert, connect

I recently started an Xcode project, and its mostly web-based, in the sense it mostly works with UIWebView. I am a total noob at this. I would like to make an "No Internet Connection Alert". Basically An Alert that comes up if you have no internet connection. I have tried using the Reachability but since I'm such a noob, I didn't manage to figure ANYTHING out.. Heres my view controller:
This is my .h file: P.S: My WebView is called 'webone'.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)refreshClicks:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webone;
@end
```

And This is My .m file:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize webone;


-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.lostcraft.net/mobile"]; 
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
    [webone loadRequest:req];    
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)awakeFromNib{  //IGNORE
    [self refreshClicks:self]; //IGNORE
}

-(IBAction)refreshClicks:(id)sender{//IGNORE
    [webone loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.lostcraft.net/mobile"]]];//IGNORE
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setWebone:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in your .m file

Under Your IBAction:

```
NSString *web = @"http://YOUR WEB ADRESS HERE";
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:web];
NSURLRequest *requestUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webdone loadRequest:requestUrl];
```

Then somewhere in your .m

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webdone didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please check     your internet connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];

}
```

go into connections tab in interface builder in xcode

[image]

Right click from the delegate as shown in the picture (the top option) and drag it to your view contoller where you have your web view (webdone)

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work. Is there anything else I could put, besides the reachability classes because this seems to be not working. I urgently need this.

Comment: It does work, After you have put that code in, go into connections tab and control drag "delegate" (the option  at the top) to your view controller.

Comment: Do you have skype, so you can tell me further?

Comment: Thanks so much! Great! +1 For you bro!